# PAW, how to grep value from response and set it as environment variable

Tags: paw-app

I have to usually run the following concept.
1. Login
2. Do some other requests

When I login, I receive a token that I can use in the Authorisation header in my other requests. Can I somehow grep a value from the login request, set it as value to an environment variable and then have it automatically reuse it in my other requests?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, if you want to have a Skype call so I can help you out, I'll be happy. Otherwise, @davidolrik's answer is exactly what you need, I think.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want a *Response Parsed Body Dynamic Value*

You can find the docs [here](https://luckymarmot.com/paw/doc/Response_Parsed_Body_Dynamic_Value)